# Android: unexpected activity life-cycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Who can explain the following behavior?

**First activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(">>><<<", "onStart: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(">>><<<", "onStop: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(">>><<<", "onPause: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(">>><<<", "onResume: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

**Second activity:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(">>><<<", "onStart: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(">>><<<", "onStop: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(">>><<<", "onPause: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(">>><<<", "onResume: " + getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <Button
      android:onClick="onClick"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Click here!"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Transparent"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**Styles:**

```
  <style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Turn on "Don't keep activities" option in "Developer options" for simple reproducing.
2. Launch the app and press the button to call the second activity.
3. Press Home button.
4. Go back to the app.

**Expected logs after step #4:**

```
onStart: MainActivity
onStart: SecondActivity
onResume: SecondActivity
```

**Actual logs after step #4:**

```
onStart: MainActivity
onResume: MainActivity
onStart: SecondActivity
onResume: SecondActivity
```

Why MainActivity resumes? Why doesn't pause after resume before start SecondActivity?